# Python SpeechRecognition while playing music

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech

My program is playing music, but I want to stop it using the `SpeechRecognition` module.
The problem is, the module is hearing the music too. Is there a way to remove the music from `SpeechRecognition`?

Code:

```
#!Imports

#!speechRecognition
r = sr.Recognizer()

#!Variables
result = None
currentTime = 0
window = None

#!listenInBackground

#!controllTime
def controllTime():
    global currentTime
    global window
    #~checkforTime
    if currentTime != 0:
        time.sleep(1)
        currentTime = currentTime-1
        print(currentTime)
        controllTime()
    else:
        os.system("taskkill /f /im "+"chrome.exe")
        
#!Videosearch
def searchMusic(s):
    global result 
    global currentTime
    global window

    #~GetLink
    url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query="+str(s).replace(" ", "")
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())
    result = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+video_ids[0]

    #~getElements
    video = pafy.new(result)
    currentTime = video.length

    #~openWebsite
    window = webbrowser.open(result)

    #~StartCounters
    Thread(target = controllTime).start()

searchMusic("The End")
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can, because the microphone can't separate the music from your voice( as it records everything it hears)

Comment: Ok. Then I have another Idea. Is there a way to use the listen_in_background function, to listen and recognize it immediately?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. I myself only tried the library once.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I now try to do it with listen and stop the recording after 3 seconds